# How to solve this mixed partial derivative with ndsolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I tried the following mixed pde but although I get an interpolation function - I still can't plot it.

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, x] + Exp[x*t]*u[x, t] == 0, 
   u[-25, t] == Exp[-100], u[25, t] == Exp[-100], u[x, 0] == Exp[0]}, 
  u, {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0, 25}]

Plot3D[sol1, {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0, 25}]
```

I remember using the exponential trick for the boundaries. Is there another trick to get a solution for this?

Comment: NDSolve gives you replacement rules, not a function. To get a function and plot it, you would e.g. write:fun = u /. sol1[[1]];
Plot3D[fun[x, t], {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0, 25}]  But first you must get your boundary and initial conditions right, otherwise the function is garbage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give suitable boundary condition. For example,

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, x] + Exp[x*t]*u[x, t] == 0, 
   u[-25, t] == Exp[-100 t], u[x, 0] == Exp[0]}, 
  u, {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0, 25}]
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol1, {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0, 25}]
```

Comment: Thank you. What is a suitable boundary condition. Technically, this pde has only the initial condition - I added the rest trying to get something back.